# Foreground and background color too similar in Cinnamon

Tags: linux, fedora, vim, cinnamon, gvim

After installing Cinnamon on FC25, I can no longer easily use GVim. All my title bars blend too closely for me. For some reason, I didn't have this issue on FC24 and Cinnamon, so I'm leaning towards this being a Cinnamon theme issue. I'm trying to pick some theme that's as close to Windows XP as possible.

When I drag the window to resize it, the foreground goes to something dark, and the background goes to white. When the dragging handle is released, it goes back to something that I can't distinguish.[image: GVim Screenshot with "Testing"]

The desktop theme is Mint-XP, and I've tried Arc, Arc Solid, Dark, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually change the colours of elements in themes in the appearance options of the control panel in Cinnamon.

Comment: I'm looking for a specific setting that addresses the gvim background vs foreground.